# On Solaris, what is a terse way to get the fully qualified domain name (fqdn) for the current host

Tags: solaris-10

When I want the fully qualified domain name on Linux, I can write ...

```
hostname --fqdn
```

To get the same thing on Solaris, is it necessary to write ...

```
cut -f 2-3 /etc/hosts | grep ^`hostname`\t | cut -f 2
```

... or is there something more brief?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [here](http://automatthias.wordpress.com/2008/09/11/fqdn-n-solaris-10/):

> The `hostname` command should return an FQDN...
>   ...
>   The solution is to edit /etc/nodename and put the FQDN in there and reboot.
>
> ```
>     echo foo.your.domain.com > /etc/nodename
> ```

You might also be able to use:

```
getent hosts `hostname` | cut -f 3
```

or similar.

Comment: Will "getent hosts | cut -f 3" depend on the layout of /etc/hosts ?

Comment: @Thomas: Yes. That command retrieves the same field as your command. You could try to use a `sed` or AWK command to be more flexible and selective.

Answer (score 2):

Your method depends upon the /etc/hosts file being formatted in a particular way, on a S10 system I have to hand it returns loghost which is incorrect.

If set up you can ask the DNS system with

```
dig -x your.ip.add.ress +short
```

or if you are using NIS then

```
echo `hostname`.`domainname`
```

or you could setup `/etc/nodename` as Dennis suggests.

Answer (score 2):

Would two digs be better than one?

```
dig -x `dig +short "$(hostname)"` +short
```

Just be mindful of the trailing dot.