# Solaris equivalent of hostname -f?

Tags: solaris, fqdn

What is the Solaris equivalent of the Linux `hostname -f` command?  On Solaris, when I type `hostname`, I receive the short name but I need to get the FQDN.

Typing `hostname -f` sets the short name to be "-f", and the manpage for `hostname` is pitiful.

Comment: /etc/nodename just lists shortname for the server. The /etc/hostname.* files are all giving me an error when I try to cat them :(

Comment: What errors do you get with /etc/hostname.if? If those are corrupted then you have bigger problems.

Comment: This question has also been asked before. Here's the previous answer: http://serverfault.com/questions/229706/on-solaris-what-is-a-terse-way-to-get-the-fully-qualified-domain-name-fqdn-fo

Answer (score 2):

This is likely to work:

```
perl -mNet::Domain -e 'print Net::Domain::hostfqdn(), "\n"'
```

but it's not guaranteed.  You can view the module source:

```
perldoc -m Net::Domain
```

to see how it works (if you know Perl well enough).

Answer (score 2):

If you are on a system that the DNS knows about, you could try this:

```
bash-3.00# nslookup `hostname` | grep 'Name:' | awk '{print $2}'
ep60.bar.foo.com
```

or, as suggested by a commenter, use "host" instead of nslookup:

```
host $(hostname) | cut -d" " -f1
```

I tested this successfully on Linux, Solaris, AIX, and HP-UX.

Comment: `nslookup` has been deprecated for a long time. `host` or `dig` are preferred and would involve fewer pipes: `host $(hostname) | cut -d" " -f1`

Comment: @JamesO'Gorman `nslookup` is part of the POSIX standard, only a hairbrain OS wouldn't include it these days.

Comment: @ChrisS True, and `nslookup` generally still comes with `host` and `dig` in the BIND utilities package (OS/distro dependent) but the output from `dig` is BIND zonefile-compatible and `host` is slightly easier to parse, therefore I'd say it's better to use `host` or `dig` _if you can_.

Answer (score 2):

```
check-hostname | awk '{ print $NF }'
```